# How to add attribute option label and value in magento by coding?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I would like to add, update and delete magento product attribute option value and label ?
Not by admin but by coding....

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Hello All,

I got it.
```

Here I have a product attribute Which name is manufacturer and I would like to add new manufacturer "adidas" by coding.
so below is the snippet for same.

Also we can delete the attribute option value by coding.

```
<?php
// add new option in manufacturer attribut by coding 'adidas' in manufacturer attribute
$attribute_code=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', "manufacturer");
$attributeInfo = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attribute_code);
$attribute_table = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute($attributeInfo);
$options = $attribute_table->getAllOptions(false);
 //$options = $attributeInfo->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
$_optionArr = array('value'=>array(), 'order'=>array(), 'delete'=>array());
foreach ($options as $option){
    $_optionArr['value'][$option['value']] = array($option['label']);
    $checkarray[] = $option['label'];
    }
if (!in_array('adidas', $checkarray)) {
    $_optionArr['value']['option_1'] = array('adidas');
    $attributeInfo->setOption($_optionArr);
    $attributeInfo->save();
}

//Delete any option from manufacturer like 'adidas'

$attribute_code=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', "manufacturer");
$attributeInfo = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attribute_code);
$attribute_table = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute($attributeInfo);
$options = $attribute_table->getAllOptions(false);
//$options = $attributeInfo->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
$_optionArr = array('value'=>array(), 'order'=>array(), 'delete'=>array());
foreach ($options as $option){
                $_optionArr['value'][$option['value']] = array($option['label']);
                    if('adidas' == $option['label']){
                    $_optionArr['delete'][$option['value']] = true;
                    }
                }
$attributeInfo->setOption($_optionArr);
$attributeInfo->save();
?>
```